# Как взаимодействовать с rar архивами c++?

Tags: c++, zip, rar

Хочу написать подбор паролей(на лабу нужно) для rar архивов. Существуют ли какие то апишки что бы у меня как минимум был функционал открытия архива и ввода пароля? Пишу на с++ на винде. Прошу прощения если есть плохо сформулирован вопрос.

Comment: "Хочу написать брутфорс для rar архивов." Хотеть не вредно, а вот вредоносное ПО на этом форуме обсуждать не нужно. Но, по теме - утилита rar.exe

Comment: А кто мешает использовать `rar` в командной строке? Но, кстати, насколько я помню, в комплекте `rar` вроде бы шла `unrar.dll`, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Smlnc Ну так подбор паролей может использоваться не только для взлома. Бывают случаи когда просто забыл пароль. В моем случает это лаба на алгоритм подбора.

Comment: Исходники unrar, вроде, в открытом доступе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данного случая могу порекомендовать *[LibZip](http://libzip.org)* - высокоуровневую библиотеку для работы как с *.rar*, так и с *.zip* файлами. Скачать ее можно [здесь](https://libzip.org/download/), а посмотреть документацию - [здесь](https://libzip.org/documentation/). Думаю, вам понадобятся следующие статьи:

- [установка libzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759373/static-libzip-with-visual-studio-2012);
- [работа с ziptool](https://libzip.org/documentation/ziptool.html).

Обе статьи англоязычные, но все равно обязательно прочитайте их! Удачи!