# Извлечение zip архива

Tags: c++

В с++ не силен от слова совсем, но понадобился именно этот язык.
Нужно извлечь zip архив и положить рядом с самим архивом. Название папки для распаковки - первые 8 символов от md5 строки, переданной с помощью аргумента.
ide dev-c++
Желательно ткнуть носом в нужную либу)

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже задавался. Посмотрите вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808959/283475

Comment: Библиотека называется zlib